# How to cast `AggregateFunction(sumForEach, Array(UInt32))` in ClickHouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I want to replace table with new one so that column that was of type `AggregateFunction(sumForEach, Array(UInt32))` will became `AggregateFunction(sumForEach, Array(Int32))`. But I have a problem while moving data: `DB::Exception: Conversion from AggregateFunction(sumForEach, Array(UInt32)) to AggregateFunction(sumForEach, Array(Int32)) is not supported: while converting source column valuesCol to destination column valuesCol.` What should I do to overcome this restriction?

UPD: Tables are `Distributed` over `ReplicatedSummingMergeTree`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
INSERT INTO newTable (
    otherColumns,
    valuesCol
)
SELECT
    otherColumns,
    arrayReduce(
        'sumForEachState',
        [cast(finalizeAggregation(viewMapAbsolutes), 'Array(Int32)')]
    ) AS valuesCol
FROM oldTable;
```

Comment: `arrayReduce` could be replaced by `initializeAggregation`

Answer (score 1):

Try to

- convert the intermediate state to value
- change type of value
- convert new value to the intermediate state

```sql
SELECT
    sumForEachState(new_value) AS new_state,
    toTypeName(new_state) AS type_name
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        sumForEachState(cast([1, 2], 'Array(UInt32)')) AS origin_state,
        finalizeAggregation(origin_state) AS origin_value,
        cast(origin_value, 'Array(Int32)') AS new_value
)

/*
┌─new_state─┬─type_name───────────────────────────────────┐
│           │ AggregateFunction(sumForEach, Array(Int32)) │
└───────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────┘
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposal, it helped me enhance my answer! Unfortunately `sumForEachState` is aggregate function requiring `GROUP BY`, which is very expensive in my case. Nevertheless `arrayReduce` function applied to one element array allows not to use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @TimofeyGorshkov no problem, I'm glad to help you.